# how to execute jenkins pipeline from config file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a generic multibranch project that I use on about 100 different git repos. The jenkins jobs are automatically generated and the only difference is the git repo.

Since they all build in the same way and I don't want to copy the same jenkins groovy file in all repos, I use "Build configuration -> mode -> by default jenkinsfile".

It breaks the rule to put the jenkinsfile in SCM as I would prefer to do. To minimize the impact, I would like that groovy file to only checkout the "real" jenkinsfile and execute it.

I use that script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'docker'}
    stages {
        stage('jenkinsfile checkout') {
            steps {
               checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                  branches: [[name: 'master']], 
                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                  extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
                  relativeTargetDir: 'gipc_synthesis']], 
                  submoduleCfg: [], 
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@camtl1bitmirror.gad.local:7999/mtlstash/mvt/gipc_synthesis.git']]]
               ) 
            }
        } 

        stage('Load user Jenkinsfile') {
           //agent any
           steps {
             load 'gipc_synthesis/jenkins/synthesis_job.groovy'
           }
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem I have with that is I can't have another pipeline in the groovy file I am loading.  I don't want to define only functions but really the whole pipeline in that file. Any solution to that problem? I am also interested in solution that would completely avoid the whole issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a shared library with your pipeline inside:

```
// my-shared.git: vars/build.groovy
def call(String pathToGit) // and maybe additional params 
{
    pipeline {
        agent { ... }
        stages {
          stage('jenkinsfile checkout') {
            steps {
               checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                  branches: [[name: 'master']], 
                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                  extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
                  relativeTargetDir: 'gipc_synthesis']], 
                  submoduleCfg: [], 
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: pathToGit]]]
               ) 
            }
          } 
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in your Jenkinsfile e.g. like this:

```
#!groovy
@Library('my-shared') _

def pathToGit = 'ssh://git@camtl1bitmirror.gad.local:7999/mtlstash/mvt/gipc_synthesis.git'

build(pathToGit)
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. I must admit I did not understand how it would solve my problem the first time I read it but I found more information about global libraries there: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/. I will definitely try it.